# Cannot connect to Redis container from Celery Workers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, celery, fastapi

I've dockerized a setup for FastAPI + celery worker + Redis application, however I have a problem with connection to Redis from other containers.

While running it locally (API with uvicorn + celery worker in different process + Redis), it works perfectly, however I cannot establish connection within containers.

The problem I'm receiving when running my worker with docker-compose is:

> worker    | TypeError: Channel._connparams..Connection.disconnect() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: app
    container_name: app
    working_dir: /code
    command: pipenv run uvicorn src.app:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload
    volumes:
      - "./app:/code/"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
    links:
      - redis
    networks:
      - local

  worker:
    build:
      context: app
    container_name: worker
    command: pipenv run celery -A src.worker.celery worker --loglevel=info
    volumes:
      - "./app:/code/"
    depends_on:
      - redis
    links:
      - redis
    networks:
      - local

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    hostname: redis
    image: redis:7.0.9-alpine
    networks:
      - local

networks:
  local:
    name: local
```

And my worker setup:

```
celery = Celery(__name__)
celery.conf.broker_url = "redis://redis:6379"
celery.conf.result_backend = "redis://redis:6379"
```

Besides, when I'm trying to run a simple ping from another containers, like:

```
from redis import Redis

redis_hostname = "redis"
r = Redis(redis_hostname, socket_connect_timeout=1)
r.ping()
```

I'm getting timeouts only.

Any idea what can be wrong with my setup?

Comment: are you sure that's the exact error ?  And where is that coming from?  that doesn't look related to connecting to redis

Comment: I'm getting it inside my worker container, after not being able to establish connection with Redis and receiving a timeout.

Comment: you can test the redis connection from the worker container (install redis client `redis-cli` or just use netcat / telnet  or something, redis protocol is very simple).  Seems like you have networking stuff configured correctly